# SQL: How to properly nest TRIM() method

Tags: sql, oracle, trim

I'm working on a homework problem, and my function works fine. I accomplished what my professor is asking, but I need help formatting my last statement using the Trim() method. I don't know how to properly nest it with 2 other methods. I did it properly on the first line, but I'm having difficulty with line 3 to format the dates for the "FIRST_PAY DAY" column. Below is my working function with one Trim() method-

```
SQL> SELECT empno, ename, sal, TRIM(TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'Month')) || ' ' || 
     TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'fmddTH, YYYY') AS "HIRE DAY",
  2  TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(hiredate, 'FRIDAY'),
  3  'Month fmddTH, YYYY') "FIRST_PAY DAY"
  4  FROM emp;
```

Thank you!

Here is the code I tried doing, but to no luck-

```
SQL> SELECT empno, ename, sal, TRIM(TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'Month')) || ' ' || 
     TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'fmddTH, YYYY') AS "HIRE DAY",
  2  TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(hiredate, 'FRIDAY'),
  3  TRIM(TO_CHAR('Month')) || ' ' || TO_CHAR('fmddTH, YYYY')) 
     "FIRST_PAY DAY"
  4  FROM emp;
```

"HIRE DAY" column is formatted correctly with TRIM() method, but "First_PAY DAY" column isn't. Below is a portion of my output from both date columns-

```
  HIRE DAY              FIRST_PAY DAY
 ___________________   ___________________
 May 1st, 1981         May       8th, 1981
```

Comment: Explicitly show what you are getting as output, and what you expect as output.

Comment: I edited the post so you can see. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use `'fmMonth'` - the 'fm' will remove the padding. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#BABDAEDF

Comment: This works great! But I get a leading '0' for single-digit dates. Any suggestions? Here is my code- 'fmMonth fmddTH, YYYY') "FIRST_PAY DAY"

Comment: I guess take out the 'fm' in the 'ddTH'. Works perfectly now. Thank you, @kfinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select to_char(hiredate,'fmMonth ddth, yyyy') as hiredate,
to_char(next_day(hiredate, 'FRIDAY'),'fmMonth ddth, yyyy') as payday
from emp;
```

Anything wrong with the above?

Best regards,
Stew Ashton

Answer (score 2):

The month value is bigger, so it needs to be trimmed by itself.

Try.

```
TRIM(TRIM(TO_CHAR('Month'))) || ' ' || TO_CHAR('fmddTH, YYYY')) "FIRST_PAY DAY"
```

Your code is doing the concatenation of the fields first, then trimming the results.  By that time it is too late to trim the area between the month and date.

Oracle has pretty good date formatting.  It would be worth a few more minutes to explore the date formatting that is available.  Odds are you can generate the output that you want with one **to_char(date, 'several-date-format-codes-can-go-here')** call.

In response to your comment, here is a working example using sysdate instead of hiredate and selecting from the dummy dual table instead of emp.

```
select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Month') || 
       ' ' || 
       TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'fmddTH, YYYY') AS "HIRE DAY", 
       TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(sysdate, 'FRIDAY')), 
       TRIM(TRIM(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Month'))) || 
       ' ' || 
       TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'fmddTH, YYYY') "FIRST_PAY DAY"
       FROM dual;
```

It looks like you were missing hiredate on a few of your TO_CHARs

Comment: Thank you for helping, but I tried your code, and it doesn't work. Here is what I typed-                                                                                                               
   SQL> SELECT empno, ename, sal, TRIM(TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'Month')) || ' ' ||
        2  TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'fmddTH, YYYY') AS "HIRE DAY",
        3  TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(hiredate, 'FRIDAY'),
        4  TRIM(TRIM(TO_CHAR('Month'))) || ' ' || TO_CHAR('fmddTH, YYYY')) 
            "FIRST_PAY DAY"
        5  FROM emp;